# Long idle time on event clicks on Angular webapp

Tags: javascript, angular, web-applications, angular2-changedetection

I have an [Angular10](https://angular.io/) web application.
While analyzing the performance with DevTools I noticed that the `click` event takes quite a long time, most of it is spent doing nothing, then a `globalZoneAwareCallback` is called followed by a microtask

Here's a snapshot of the flame chart. When the user clicks on a button, the task takes several milliseconds (in this case 107ms) but most of the time is spent doing nothing.

Is this expected or there's something I'm missing? I do use the default change detection strategy.

Is that an idle time or is the app doing something really time consuming?

[image]

**EDIT**

I found out that only the first time the event takes quite a significant bit of time (some initialization going on?). Subsequent events are in a reasonable range (40ms-50ms).

Comment: Does it do it when it's built for production?  Can you share some code?

Comment: @cjd82187 I'll share some results asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialization or some other operations done by Angular. Subsequent events don't show the problem